# What to do when Console.SetOut doesn't work?

Tags: .net, console, saxon, ikvm

I feel like I've hit a wall.  I'm working on a web application that uses the Saxon library to perform XSLT transformations.  The application used to be a console application that simply printed output to the console, but then, we decided that we wanted to control the application from the web.

I wrote a custom `TextWriter` class that outputs to the web page and used `Console.SetOut` and `Console.SetError` to direct my Console output to the web page.

However, Saxon is using some sort of Java compatibility library which doesn't seem to be affected by `Console.SetOut`, so when I run the application on the web, internal Saxon errors don't appear on the web page.

The short version of my question is: suppose that I call `Console.SetOut` to change the location that console text is output to and it doesn't work.      What then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that Console.SetOut and Console.SetError don't work. Saxon on .NET is using the OpenJDK library cross-compiled to .NET by use of IKVMC, and I would expect the mapping of output streams to be such that these methods worked. If you think there's a bug here, the place to report it is on the Saxonica support site at saxonica.plan.io, with an example that reproduces the problem.

However, a better way of redirecting Saxon error messages might be to register an ErrorListener of your own. You can't do this directly in the .NET Saxon API, but you can do it by getting the Controller from the XsltTransformer, and calling its setErrorListener method with an implementation of the javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener interface.

Comment: We've since confirmed with Jeroen Frijters that Console.SetOut and Console.SetError do not affect data written to System.out and System.err by the Java part of an IKVM application.